# Why is msdeploy failing when creating a wordpress site in azure using the resource group gallery template?

Tags: wordpress, powershell, azure, msdeploy, azure-web-app-service

Im trying to create a wordpress site in Azure using the gallery template for wordpress.

Im running this command:

```
New-AzureResourceGroup `
-ResourceGroupName "WPGroup1" `
-Location "North Europe" `
-GalleryTemplateIdentity WordPress.WordPress.0.4.2-preview `
-hostingPlanName "WPPlan1" `
-siteName "WPCustomer1" `
-siteLocation "North Europe" `
-sku Standard `
-databaseName "dbwpcustomer1" `
-databaseLocation "North Europe" `
-databaseSku Free `
-webDeploy_AuthenticationKey 'mSUuC&-27L2Dl|meu{rG@RT>K*}gA!`BF<nv=;BvKAu^;O4tcp0aqUJRzwspo>n'`
-webDeploy_SecureAuthenticationKey '|5!@q{G&L xvlszlC4.9CN6bJ.IA|Qj,S_+>iqKiz|&PlIB61a00-t`,/z*?L=#z'`
-webDeploy_LoggedInKey 'Pv;jk/&-Bp@lsaVw|y5h<b$8i04^)HW2D5}~|G#!#3fZ}V4MS=rE}hJZrk7@keW4'`
-webDeploy_NonceKey '{~0|AVTb6oAv9<~FQcp%vu#2cbc|TWD$`Q%b|Olv4YU$wf##*mXofJ]M^]Y.V{L0'`
-webDeploy_AuthenticationSalt '*_LJ_Z%6-t|W+]Z(k6 Mjg3CvD.S@cRoV3#+6(tK?R#K`7,?bEhh2Q->3,V+[N:!'`
-webDeploy_SecureAuthenticationSalt 'EFC?lh|_thz(`J}ma^.2c6zjrXgV>Dh~0PBw>3:&Kybt_mzZ>{#OD^DHqiCc3&8h'`
-webDeploy_LoggedInSalt 'wc,{@J<q8-YL_1@ MB=:~Nu2^vzeJ]&AB()LC71-av^6M1%^sm;}L-z|yMTVU;fj'`
-webDeploy_NonceSalt '$q;W[]F@Gj08E3{Io5Y0L|n1XmmEBHVt39s**v`-mxqC?.%l+=8]c&|7x}AZdO/2'
```

The resource group gets created with a site and a database but the deployment of wordpress fails. I get this error message:

**New-AzureResourceGroup : 9:12:22 AM - Resource Microsoft.Web/sites/Extensions 
'WPCustomer1/MSDeploy' failed with message 'The resource operation completed with terminal 
provisioning state 'failed'.'
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureResourceGroup `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureResourceGroup], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.NewAzureResourceGroupCommand**

I have tried to download the .json file and the package, put it in my own storage group and changed the path in the .json file but I get the same error.

Anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: This fails if you try and do the same action via the Web Portal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution,

The problem has to do with the keys, when I tried with only numbers & letters it works!